# onCreateDrawableState Never Called

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, viewgroup, statelistdrawable

All,

I've got a ViewGroup subclass which overrides `OnCreateDrawableState()` (Xamarin.Android is in C# so forgive the Pascal Casing).

My override of `OnCreateDrawableState()` never gets called, however.  I've tried calling `RefreshDrawableState()`, `DrawableStateChanged()`. `RequestLayout()`, and `Invalidate()`.

Nothing seems to work.  This is the method:

```
/// <summary>
/// Handles the create drawable state event by adding in additional states as needed.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="extraSpace">Extra space.</param>
protected override int[] OnCreateDrawableState (int extraSpace)
{
    int[] drawableState = base.OnCreateDrawableState(extraSpace + 3);

    if (Completed)
    {
        int[] completedState = new int[] { Resource.Attribute.completed };
        MergeDrawableStates(drawableState, completedState);
    }

    if (Required)
    {
        int[] requiredState = new int[] { Resource.Attribute.required };
        MergeDrawableStates(drawableState, requiredState);
    }

    if (Valid)
    {
        int[] validState = new int[] { Resource.Attribute.valid };
        MergeDrawableStates(drawableState, validState);
    }

    Android.Util.Log.Debug("ROW_VIEW", "OnCreateDrawableState Called");

    return drawableState;
}
```

I assume it'll work OK - but it just never gets called.  The ViewGroup itself is nested in a `ListView` and/or a `LinearLayout` but nothing seems to help.

This [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10223871/oncreatedrawablestate-never-call) has no answers that work for me.

Comment: This is most likely because you didnt assign any statefull Drawable to your View

Comment: @pskink I have a state list drawable set as the background which has my custom states and the android state_pressed.

Comment: are you sure it is a statefull drawable?

Answer (score 1):

Edit: (I edited my previous answer incorrect answer where assumed you were implementing the Checkable interface)

OnCreateDrawableState seems to be propagated from the leaf nodes up to it's parent nodes (ViewGroups) only if a child element (leaf) declares `android:duplicateParentState` for instance in a Textview. As I understand it RefreshDrawableState goes down to the leaves and OnCreateDrawableState up from the leaves if `android:duplicateParentState="true"` is set, I haven't done a thorough analysis though, would be interested in any good pointers to documentation.

The following layout as an item in a ListView will cause onCreateDrawableState on MyLinearLayout to be called:

```
<com.example.android.MyLinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   ...>    
    <TextView
        ...
        android:duplicateParentState="true"/>    
</com.example.android.MyLinearLayout>
```

This won't:

```
<com.example.android.MyLinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   ...>    
    <TextView
        ...
        android:duplicateParentState="false"/>    
</com.example.android.MyLinearLayout>
```

Neither will this (The LinearLayout won't propagate up):

```
<com.example.android.MyLinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   ...>    
    <LinearLayout 
        ...
        android:duplicateParentState="false">
        <TextView
            ...
            android:duplicateParentState="true"/>    
    </LinearLayout>
</com.example.android.MyLinearLayout>
```

This again will:

```
<com.example.android.MyLinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   ...>    
    <LinearLayout 
        ...
        android:duplicateParentState="true">
        <TextView
            ...
            android:duplicateParentState="true"/>    
    </LinearLayout>
</com.example.android.MyLinearLayout>
```

Note that there seems to be some amalgam with the implementation of the Checkable interface.

The Checkable interface can be implemented by the Views that are immediate children in a ListView, GridView etc. There is no need to have it implemented further down the view tree.

In this case the ListView when in choice mode will call setChecked on the Checkable interface:

http://androidxref.com/4.3_r2.1/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/widget/ListView.java#1899

```
if (mChoiceMode != CHOICE_MODE_NONE && mCheckStates != null) {
            if (child instanceof Checkable) {
                ((Checkable) child).setChecked(mCheckStates.get(position));
            }
```

The implementation of the Checkable usually adds a drawable state by overriding OnCreateDrawableState. See my other post for an example of this:
[MvxListView checkable list item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18672562/mvxlistview-checkable-list-item)

Comment: Hrm... this still doesn't really help.  My custom states don't get called.  The only thing that I've found that works is programmatically setting & unsetting the `Pressed` state - after that my states are respected..

Comment: Here is a working example, using your code from above: https://github.com/takoyakich/mvvmcross-samples/tree/master/DrawableStates