# ListView in navigation drawer unable to show selections visually

Tags: c#, android, android-listview, xamarin, navigation-drawer

I have an activity screen that shows a ListView. This ListView allows the user to select items to their heart's content. I have no problems with it.

However, the screen also has a Navigation Drawer. In that is another ListView. I have manually set one of its items to be selected/checked. However, nothing visual happens in that ListView when the navigation drawer is open. If I programmatically query it, I am told that one item is checked and the position of it is what I would expect.

Am I doing something wrong?

My xml for the screen looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/NavigationDrawerLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/folderList"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:listSelector="@android:color/darker_gray" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawerView"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start">
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listNavFolders"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:listSelector="@android:color/holo_red_light"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
            android:dividerHeight="0dp"
            android:background="#111" />
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

I set the selection with this code. It is C# because I am using Xamarin, but I don't think that should make a difference.

```
this.drawerList.SetSelection(pos);
this.drawerList.SetItemChecked(pos, true);
```

A call to `CheckedItemCount` or `CheckedItemPosition` both indicate that the values have been set. I am reasonably sure that I have the ListView set up properly, since there is another ListView on the screen that is working without any issues.

Does anyone have a suggestion as to what I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

You missing that items in your drawerList must implement ICheckable interface for SetItemChecked(pos, true) to work.

If you use Xamarin + MvvmCross, I'm recommend you use [this aproach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18672562/mvxlistview-checkable-list-item).

For android-style DrawerLayout work just adapt [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8369927/1112177) for csharp.